# To convert .htm page extension in .asp

Tags: c#-4.0

I have converted .htm page extension in .asp ,but on run time the error has been occur in browser...

" This type of page is not served.

Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.asp' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /WebSite1/HTMLPage.asp

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1  "

Please revert me back.

Comment: Try aspx instead. asp is the extension of the ASP Classic technology.

Comment: But sir, I wanna convert in ASP.
I try to convert in ASPX and it's work.
It is possible or not to convert in ASP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **Classic ASP Not Installed by Default on IIS 7.0 and IIS 7.5**

To support and configure ASP applications on your Web server, you must install and enable the ASP module.

Check out the [Product IIS docs](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp) or you can follow a checklist like the one on  this artiche: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis to get your internet information server works with *ASP*

The steps are little different depending on your version of Windows therefore you could refer directly to [this tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis)

*EDIT*

Since you mention to have some problem working on Visual Studio 2010 I've tested on Seven (win7) the following check-list:

Notice that I need to run Visual Studio 2010 as Administrator ( right click the icon and Run As Administrator ) to be able to browse Local Intener Information Server in the next step.

When you run Visual Studio As Administrator UAC Ask to confirm, in here say "YES"

Once opened "Visual Studio 2010", follow this sequence of commands starting from menu:

- File
- "New Web Site"
- "Asp Net Empty Site"

look on the bottom of the dialog, in  "Web location" select "HTTP" click on "Browse" and select "Default Web Site"

look on the top right of the dialog there is an icon to create a new virtual folder:

- Alias Name: *"MyASPSite"*
- Folder: *"C:\MyASPSite"*  ..we suppose that C:\MyASPSite in an existing folder on your disk or select another one of your choice
- Select checkbox [x] *"Create IIS Application"*
- Confirm

Web Location: `http://localhost/MyASPSite`

Click on the OK button to confirm

If VS ask "Do you to enable ASP.NET 4.0 on the webServer ?" say "NO"

In Solution Explorer select the site

- Add New Item
- select kind of item: "Text File"
- Name: MyASPPage.asp

in the editor create your example page such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("My first ASP script!")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Save the page and open it: Right-Click on the page in the solution explorer and select  "View in Browser"

The page will display correctly in the browser.

Optionally you would add at the top of the file:

```
    <%@ language="vbscript" %>
```

..close and reopen the file. You should then see intellisense for, say, Response in <% %> and  blocks.

Comment: Thank you sir for replying.
I am using win7 and Visual Studio 2010, .net framework 4.0 and had tried all of the following things shown in this tutorial but since same error is coming.

Comment: @rajan-vachhani Just Edited the answer , let me know if this works for you too.